# How do I get the bytestream of a sound file from a server to be saved as a SoundEffect or SoundEffectInstance?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to do something very basic, but for some reason it's just not clicking.

This is the code I have to get a sound from the resources and save them as a stream so I can use the sounds for nefarious purposes.

```
 /// Loads a wav file into an XNA Framework SoundEffect.
    private void LoadSound(String SoundFilePath, out SoundEffect Sound)
    {
        // For error checking, assume we'll fail to load the file.
        Sound = null;

        try
        {
            // Holds informations about a file stream.

            //StreamResourceInfo SoundFileInfo =  App.GetResourceStream(new Uri(SoundFilePath, UriKind.Relative));

            // Create the SoundEffect from the Stream
            Sound = SoundEffect.FromStream(SoundFileInfo.stream);

            soundEffectInstance = Sound.CreateInstance();
            soundEffectInstance.IsLooped = true;
            soundEffectInstance.Play();

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            // Display an error message
            MessageBox.Show("Couldn't load sound " + SoundFilePath);
        }
    }
```

Trying to change this code so that the file comes from an aboslute path on my server instead of the internal resources, but nothing seems to work.  What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I'll post the answer I ended up using later today.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `DynamicSoundEffectInstance` to play sound from byte array. So, save downloaded sound into a binary file, and use it when needed.

Maybe, it helps you

Comment: @Ku6popr I keep getting an error that the byteArray is the wrong size, any ideas about this?

Comment: `DynamicSoundEffectInstance` is used raw PCM wave data without any headers. The buffer must conform to the format alignment. `BlockAlignment = BytesPerSample * AudioChannels`, BytesPerSample = 2 bytes

Comment: Thanks. However, this turned out to not be the correct answer.  Apparently when downloading the file, all the bytes are put into the array, so I couldn't use a buffer to add them to the file. I had to create a normal soundEffect with the fully bytearray, but it certainly put me on the right track.